# React Native fetch() error in version 0.44.0

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, fetch, emulation

This is a react native test code using version 0.44.0 in android emulator. I am able to fetch data from many sites, but some websites cannot be fetched.One such website is provided below.

When I upgrade react native version to 0.55.0, **I am able** to fetch the data. But, in my main project, I have been using version 0.44.0 and cannot upgrade it. So, I need a solution without upgrading react native version. I have gone through many stackoverflow pages and found solutions for ios, localhost etc. But, couldn't find any solution for this problem.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { Text,View } from 'react-native';


export default class App extends Component {

  checkaccess = () => {
    url = 'https://example.com/wc-api/v3/'
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('got')
       // console.log(response.json())
        return response.json()
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('error',error)
      })
      .done()
}


  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.checkaccess()}
        <Text>test</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And the console log is :

```
error TypeError: Network request failed
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (index.bundle:12366)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (index.bundle:13277)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (index.bundle:15382)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (index.bundle:15238)
    at index.bundle:15333
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (index.bundle:3851)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (index.bundle:2090)
    at index.bundle:1948
    at MessageQueue.__guard (index.bundle:2062)
    at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (index.bundle:1947)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
fetch(url, {
    credentials: 'include',
    ...otherOptions,
});
```

For other option or understanding check [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14154) discussion on github [react-native](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14154) issues